# Is it possible to expose LDAP "compliant" data through a REST API without an LDAP server?

Tags: c#, wcf, ldap

Let me first state that I know next to nothing about LDAP and this question is more conceptual in nature than anything else. Since this is a long post, here is the question in it's simplest form:

*how can I expose contact data in an existing SQL Server database to LDAP clients in the easiest way possible?*

**SCENARIO**

The organization I work for has developed a very simple internal CRM system - actually it's more of a glorified contact management system than CRM, but full of contact's information nonetheless - and they now want the ability to easily expose all of the contact information to other desktop and mobile clients like Outlook and/or iOS devices and I've been assigned to figure out how to do this.

The first thing I did was open Outlook and see what kind of Internet address books can be added; in Outlook 2007, the only option I'm seeing is LDAP. Next, I looked at an iOS device and it also supports LDAP address books. Thus, it seems like LDAP is what is needed to accomplish this goal...

**RESEARCHING LDAP**

As stated in the beginning, I know next to nothing about LDAP and researching it for this purpose didn't get me very far. I certainly do not want to setup an entire LDAP server and I have no need for LDAP security, etc. (at least as I understand it, I don't), all I need to do is expose contact information from the existing CRM database "the LDAP way."

The consensus I seem to be seeing in my research is to install an LDAP server such as OpenLDAP and configure it to use SQL Server (i.e., the existing CRM database) as the backing store thus effectively exposing the database records to LDAP clients. This just seems overly complex and I'm hoping that there's an easier way to expose contact records in LDAP form.

**THE REST IDEA**

The idea I have - which is looking like a lost cause - is to expose each user's contacts via a simple REST (or REST-like) API that returns contact information in the LDAP form that is usable by Outlook, iOS and any other client/device that supports LDAP.

The end goal is to instruct individuals in my organization to open Outlook or their iOS device settings and type in a URI as simple as:

`https://www.ourinternalcrm.com/{username}/contacts`

**AM I WASTING MY TIME?**

Is this even remotely possible and worth investigating further or am I missing the whole point of LDAP and the way exposing data in LDAP form works?

If this is possible, can someone please help to point me in the right direction? I need to implement all of this using C# and (most likely) WCF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LDAP is a protocol in itself and is not over HTTP or another web service protocol.

If you want to develop an LDAP server that would be more complicated than using an existing LDAP server technology.

You could implement an Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM) server now called Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) and build your application or a sync service to push contact details to it, thereby eliminating the requirement to create one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I completely agree that rolling my own LDAP server would be overly complicated and that's not the goal. I'll investigate the ADLDS, but I'm trying to avoid two data stores which I'm guessing I would end up with going this route (hence your mention of a sync service).

Comment: Thanks Bernie. Your answer was the closest one to "no" that was given which, unfortunately, seems to be the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

LDAP already has a well defined URL filter syntax, just use that. See [RFC 4516](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4516.txt).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. I am trying to find a solution that doesn't require an LDAP server but can instead "fake" the server and just expose the data in an existing server in the LDAP form.

Comment: @crazyrabian But Outlook is expecting to talk the LDAP protocol to an LDAP service. Why should it make any sense out of a RESTful URL?

Comment: What I'm discovering is that it doesn't make sense. Again, the question was asked without an understanding of LDAP and trying to determine if it's possible to expose data in LDAP form without an LDAP server. The answer seems to be a simple "no" which I'm okay with, but I would like to find a way to share existing contact data to clients without setting up and syncing an LDAP server (or any other server for that matter). I am no longer venturing down this rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

So to clarify, you are trying to expose data that resides on an Apache DS LDAP server via REST, whereby the RESTFul API resides as a server side service on another server (Tomcat, Weblogic, etc)?

The interesting part I found is that Apache LDAP has a nice search and retrieve function via a JAVA API on their site - very intuitive and easy to implement. But I have the same issue and have not found a solution for integrating a REST API to spit out the data.

Some issues I found is that there seems to be a problem when trying to connect a Tomcat Server to an Apache LDAP server, so that the data via a @GET method can be serviced.

I would welcome if anyone solved this issue to post it, since there are NO solution anywhere on the web for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a specification for this called [DSML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_Services_Markup_Language). It's basically a XML markup of an LDAP data model, along with LDAP operations and their semantics. Some of the LDAP servers support this out of the box, or through libraries as the XML is also useful as an interchange format.

Comment: If DSML is returned from a REST service endpoint, do LDAP clients know what to do with the data, i.e., can I point Outlook to that endpoint and load an address book?

Comment: DSML is certainly not pervasive, but most clients aren't going to be talking to the LDAP via the web anyway. I point it out mostly in terms of if you want to map LDAP to something, then there's already an XML representation out there that you can adopt.

Comment: DSML is a SOAP based service and thus is not a REST service endpoint.